# Return no view from action in ajax requests struts 2

Tags: ajax, struts2

I have a drop down list for locale selection, when user changes it then i send an ajax request to an action where i set a session perimeter

Now the problem is that what should i return from the execute() method of the action

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can return an HTTP 200 OK, which should be an empty, successful response.

```
<result name="empty" type="httpheader">
    <param name="status">200</param>
</result>
```

I would make a global result so that you can use it any action.

Comment: You answer is great but status code should be 204 in my opinion.

Comment: Yep, 204 would be a better choice nowadays.