# How to return HTTP error status code  *and* content in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have a Controller that receives accepts http file uploads and responds with a JSON confirmation.   If there is is any sort of problem with the procsessing of the upload I want to return an HTTP error status code (e.g. 403 for malformed requests or 500 for a general processing error), but I also want to send a JSON list of detailed error messages.  I know how to return a 500 error (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263853/return-no-view-from-action-in-ajax-requests-struts-2))  but I don't know how to return the 500 code and still send content.

Here's a snippit of my code (which doesn't do what I want it to):

```
@Action(value = "upload", results = { 
  @Result(name = SUCCESS, type = "freemarker", location = "results.ftl", params = { "contentType", "text/plain" }), 
  @Result(name = ERROR, type = "freemarker", location = "error.ftl", params = { "contentType", "text/plain" }), 
  @Result(name = ERROR, type = "httpheader", params = { "status", "500" }) 
})

public String upload() {
  //do stuff
  if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getActionErrors()) {
    return SUCCESS;
  } else {
     return ERROR;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? I imagine there's a good chance your client(s) will ignore any content as soon as they see the 500 header. 500 means something catastrophic happened which prevented the response from being completed. If you have caught the errors and can describe them 500 isn't the right response. Furthermore, if your client(s) are parsing the json response why require a 500 header in the first place?

Comment: Fair point. Basically I'm using a jquery plugin that will send the file (via XHR if it support file attachments or a hidden iframe otherwise).  In addition to a success callback you can register an error callback (called if the server returns an error status code). There are other options, but registering an error callback is what I'd prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old post, but if you are using the Struts-JSON which I suggest using you can simply return an error object with what you want and attach the status code like below:

```
@Result(name = ERROR, type="json", 
        params = {"root","errorResponse", "statusCode", "500"}
)
```

Comment: This is much better than my approach.  Updating this as the "correct" solution (sorry for the delay).

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2/24/15**: [ty-danielson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27071090/103814) is the correct one.  It applies to JSON responses, which is what I wanted even though I was using freemarker templates to generate them (another bad idea).

**If you really want a freemarker template with error status code:** My original answer is *still* the wrong approach because it's bad form to access the ServletResponse from inside an action method. Struts' built-in FreemarkerResult does not accept a status code parameter, but you can easily add this functionality by subclassing it (example taken from [GBIF project](https://github.com/gbif))

```
/** 
 * Same as FreemarkerResult, but with added 'statusCode' parameter.  
 * (don't forget to register this result type in struts-config.xml)
 */
public class FreemarkerHttpResult extends FreemarkerResult {
  private int status;

  public int getStatusCode() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatusCode(int status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  @Override
  protected void postTemplateProcess(Template template, TemplateModel data) throws IOException {
    super.postTemplateProcess(template, data);
    if (status >= 100 && status < 600) {
      HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
      response.setStatus(status);
    }
  }
}
```

Then declare your action mapping like so:

```
@Action(value = "myAction", results = { 
    @Result(name = SUCCESS, type = "freemarker", location = "results.ftl"), 
    @Result(name = ERROR, type = "freemarkerhttp", location = "error.ftl", params = { "statusCode", "500"})            
})
public String myAction() {
   //do stuff, then return SUCCESS or ERROR
}
```

#### My Original Answer

So, I'm not sure if this is "proper" from a struts2 perspective, but here's a solution that acomplishes my goal of returning the http error code while still being able to render a freemarker template.  I'll mark this as the answer until a better one comes along.

```
@Action(value = "upload", results = { 
@Result(name = SUCCESS, type = "freemarker", location = "results.ftl", params = { "contentType", "text/plain"}), 
@Result(name = ERROR, type = "freemarker", location = "error.ftl", params = { "contentType", "text/plain"})            
})
    public String upload() {
       try {
       //do stuff
       } Catch(SomeExceptionType ex) {
            addActionError("you did something bad");
            HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
            response.setStatus(400);
       }


    }
```

Comment: I, too, found this the only way to accomplish a non-200 status. The "status" param in the annotation seemed to do nothing as of Struts 2.3.16

Comment: While my answer works, i've learned it is not a good idea.  Check out ty's answer  if you are serving up json.  i've also updated my answer w/ instructions on how to add a statusCode parameter to freemarker results.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for the **struts.xml** version of the accepted answer, I'm going to leave it here:

```
    <action name="upload"
        class="...">
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
        <result name="error" type="json">
            <param name="statusCode">418</param>
        </result>
        <result name="Success" type="json" />
    </action>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time to setup a test Struts2 application, but maybe have a single error result:

```
@Result(name = ERROR, type = "freemarker", location = "error.ftl",
    params = { "contentType", "text/plain", "status", "500" })
```

Comment: Hmm... no luck. Control is passed to my error.ftl  but the status code is still 200.